# assign_onchange_functions_to_inputs is not defined

Tags: jquery

I don't have the slightest clue what this error means

I *think* the relevant code is

```
$("#payment_plan_select").change(function(){ toggle_invoice_options() });
```

but not certain.

Comment: Do you have the symbol `assign_onchange_functions_to_inputs` somewhere else in your code?

Comment: he gotta have that function call in order to get the error. looks like the function itself is not defined, though. so I would say he is missing an include or part if code that defines that function

Comment: grrr. there's a function call (in two places) but no function. hadn't seen this before, so not sure why it became an issue when it did.